# How do i Take out the last value character inside a ListView Column

Tags: c#, .net, string, listview

### I have a Column that looks like this:

Column 3:

-1

-2

-2a

-2b

etc...

```
try
        {
            int count = 0; int GetLength; string Result;
            for (int i = 0; i < MMDetailsList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MMDetailsList.Items[count].SubItems[3].Text))
                {
                    GetLength = MMDetailsList.Items[count].SubItems[3].Text.Length;
                    Result = Convert.ToString(MMDetailsList.Items[count].SubItems[3].Text[GetLength]);
                    MessageBox.Show(Result);
                    //getCategoryNum = MMDetailsList.Items[count].SubItems[3].Text;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
```

What i'm doing is i wanted to know that if my series has a character at the end so i can increment it each time a button is clicked ***let say 2a if there's a character at its last value increment it to b*** and if ***b is deleted in row it would check again the last entry in the row a and would increament it back to b instead its c*** i need to check it 1st if it exist in my code i tried to check the last value of the column but it doesn't show ***my question is how do i check the last part character of the value inside the column listview i tried doing it with the code above but it's doesn't show a messagebox either.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MMDetailsList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string text = MMDetailsList.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        if(char.IsLetter(text.Last()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Last Letter :" +text.Last());
        }
    }

}
```